# Need Help to use Twilio for Voice Call initiated through Linux Hardware(Raspberry pi/Toradex) and it shall be redirected to web platform

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I am working on PoC where I need to make a voice call from Linux based hardware to a web platform.
I have started with tutorials from Twilio on Windows Desktop, just to understand the Twilio:
1. I am done with sending/receiving SMS
2. I have installed python helper library and generated Voice call to my (verified) number.
3. Understood basics of TWIML, twilmet, using forward, dial, etc.
4. Done with flask-ngrok-python tutorials from Twilio website

Queries: I need help on defining an approach for generating a call from Linux based hardware to a web platform and vice versa?

The call should be pure voice call without Text to Speech !!!

Thanking you all in anticipation.

Regards,
hgaurav

Comment: Your question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Do you have any more specific?

Comment: How to generate a call from Rasberry pi/toradex board using twilio to webbased UI?